# Unnest function only keeps first value in list

Tags: r, list, tidyr

I'm trying to do a seemingly simple task of unlisting a single column. I searched stackoverflow and it seems that I should use the `tidyr::unnest()` function. Only when I apply this function it only keeps the first valu of the vectored list in a single cell of the dataframe.

A sample of my data:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(properties.referentie = c("SDE1786673", "SDE1625351", 
"SDE1636716"), geometry.coordinates = list(c(4.75813599901064, 
52.272456042152), c(6.00720800022323, 51.9725940422743), c(4.51752499877652, 
52.1393440422071))), .Names = c("properties.referentie", "geometry.coordinates"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

My code with the incomplete output:

```
unnest(df, geometry.coordinates)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  properties.referentie geometry.coordinates
  <chr>                                <dbl>
1 SDE1786673                            4.76
2 SDE1786673                           52.3 
3 SDE1625351                            6.01
4 SDE1625351                           52.0 
5 SDE1636716                            4.52
6 SDE1636716                           52.1
```

I actually want to create two columns out of the geometry.coordinates column.

The first row and second column contains the following value: `c(4.75813599901064, 52.272456042152)` so I want one column with `4.75813599901064` and another column with the other value in that vector `52.272456042152`. It's lat and lon data.

Comment: What is your expected output.  Based on your example, it is giving the expected output.  Check the `lengths`.  It is only 2 per each `list` element `lengths(df$geometry.coordinates)#
[1] 2 2 2`

Comment: The first row and second column contains the following value: `c(4.75813599901064, 
52.272456042152)` so I want one column with `4.75813599901064` and another column with the other value in that vector `52.272456042152`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution from `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(properties.referentie) %>% 
  summarise(lat = first(geometry.coordinates), lon = last(geometry.coordinates))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  properties.referentie   lat   lon
  <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl>
1 SDE1625351             6.01  52.0
2 SDE1636716             4.52  52.1
3 SDE1786673             4.76  52.3
```

Answer (score 1):

After `unnest`ing, we can `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  unnest(geometry.coordinates) %>% 
  group_by(properties.referentie) %>% 
  mutate(rn = paste0("geometry.coordinates", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(rn, geometry.coordinates)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups: properties.referentie [3]
#    properties.referentie geometry.coordinates1 geometry.coordinates2    
#     <chr>                                 <dbl>                 <dbl>
# 1 SDE1625351                             6.01                  52.0
# 2 SDE1636716                             4.52                  52.1
# 3 SDE1786673                             4.76                  52.3
```

---

Or this can be done before the `unnest` by converting it to a `list`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(geometry.coordinates = map(geometry.coordinates,
                        ~as.list(.) %>% 
                           set_names(paste0("geometry.coordinates", seq_along(.x))) %>% 
                           as_tibble))  %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   properties.referentie geometry.coordinates1 geometry.coordinates2    
#    <chr>                                 <dbl>                 <dbl>    
# 1 SDE1786673                             4.76                  52.3
# 2 SDE1625351                             6.01                  52.0
# 3 SDE1636716                             4.52                  52.1
```

NOTE: Both the solutions work for any `length` within each `list` elements

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can using `sapply` with `unlist` to create the columns from list type column.

```
cbind(df$properties.referentie,data.frame(t(sapply(df$geometry.coordinates,unlist))))
  df$properties.referentie       X1       X2
1               SDE1786673 4.758136 52.27246
2               SDE1625351 6.007208 51.97259
3               SDE1636716 4.517525 52.13934
```